# Como setar variáveis com JSON recebido de uma requisição AJAX

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

Estou recebendo um JSON e gostaria de setar as variáveis com tais informações. Como faço isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/pessoa-gerenciar/consultar-codigo-postal",
    type: "GET",
    data: { codigoPostal: $('#PessoasEnderecosViewModel_' + rowIndice + '__CodigoPostal').val().replace("-", ""), paisId: $('#PessoasEnderecosViewModel_' + rowIndice + '__PaisId').val() },
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        var dados = JSON.stringify(data);

        var codigo = ?
        var logradouro = 



    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
    }
});
```

Comment: não precisa fazer stringfy, os dados já são um objeto json, basta um data.algumacoisa por exemplo `data.cep`

Comment: Ah tá.. Só que os dados retornam como se fosse uma classe. Tem o nome cep e dentro os fields... Como pego as informações deles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` serve para transformar um objeto numa string com o formato JSON, é exatamente o contrário do que você quer.

Se na resposta do seu servidor é enviado o `Content-Type` da resposta, `data` automaticamente será um objeto, mas na dúvida, para garantir você pode adicionar a propriedade `dataType` no seu AJAX para interpretar a resposta como um JSON e fazer o parse dela para objeto automaticamente.

Então basta acessar as propriedades desse objeto:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/pessoa-gerenciar/consultar-codigo-postal",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { codigoPostal: $('#PessoasEnderecosViewModel_' + rowIndice + '__CodigoPostal').val().replace("-", ""), paisId: $('#PessoasEnderecosViewModel_' + rowIndice + '__PaisId').val() },
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {

        var codigo = data.cep.codigo;
        var logradouro = data.cep.logadouro;



    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado @user140828!!!